# Duplicated messages using Bean Validation with JSF and Omnifaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I have a problem with JSF 2.2, Omnifaces 2.6.3 and PrimeFaces 6.1 with Client Side Validation that is causing the validation messages from Bean Validation to show twice.

If in some button I use

```
<p:commandButton value="Some Action" ajax="false" action="#{someController.action}" validateClient="false"> <!-- validation disabled to test server side validation -->
     <o:validateBean value="#{someController.bean}" showMessageFor="@violating" />
</p:commandButton>
```

The validation works, but it results in two messages for each validation:

```
NotNull validation failed
NotNull validation failed
Max validation failed
Max validation failed
```

I traced the problem to be the class **javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator** that is executing the validations along side Omnifaces **org.omnifaces.taghandler.ValidateBean**.

I tried to remove the default bean validation of JSF, but PrimeFaces Client Side Validation relies on that enabled to send the validatorIds to the client side, so it was not an option.

I did a workaround that using some group in the annotation, the default BeanValidator would not validate, but I was wondering if there was a way to not be obligated to use a group.

Thanks!

Edit:
Example project https://github.com/marcelopio/duplicatederror

Edit 2:

SomeController.class

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SomeController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6184842672181799938L;

    private Foo foo = new Foo();

    public void someAction() {
        System.out.println("action");
    }

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}
```

Foo.class

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7334434752280744719L;

    @Max(5)
    private Integer bar;

    public Integer getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(Integer bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

XHTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <title>Teste</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:messages />
            <p:outputLabel value="Bar" for="bar"/>
            <p:inputText id="bar" value="#{someController.foo.bar}" />
            <p:message for="bar" />
            <p:commandButton value="Action" action="#{someController.someAction()}" ajax="false" validateClient="false">
                <o:validateBean value="#{someController.foo}" showMessageFor="@violating" />
            </p:commandButton>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

WEB.XML

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
    <display-name>Duplicated Error</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.TRANSFORM_METADATA</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>initial.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers. Also please add the relevant code of `someController` to better help you

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, added demo project

Comment: It is preferred if you wrote the code rather than sharing a link to it... extract the relevant parts for your problem, or the ones related to the errors you get. Please check the links I mentioned as in them more guidelines are mentioned.

Comment: I already did, the meaningful part is already on the question, the controller has nothing relevant, neither the actual page. I can add the full code here and it won't help more than the already posted information. The link is a proof of that.

Comment: @MarceloPiodeCastro: You did not post any xhtml/bean that shows the messages, nor any input that can cause the messages, so it is **not** the meaningful part. Therefore a [mcve] is always requested. It also helps to narrow down the problem. Please do.

Comment: Well, I posted the full code then, since the given link was a stripped down, just to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `showMessageFor=""` attribute to control how messages are displayed [o:validateBean](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateBean) while also setting the `globalOnly` attribute of `p:messaages` to `true`.

**UPDATED**

with your use case,[o:messages](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/messages) provides the possibility to do so:

eg

```
<o:messages for="fooBar" />
<h:form id="fooBar">
      <p:outputLabel value="Bar" for="bar"/>
      <p:inputText id="bar" value="#{someController.foo.bar}" />
    <p:message for="bar" />
    <p:outputLabel value="Bar" for="foo"/>
      <p:inputText id="foo" value="#{someController.foo.bar}" />
    <p:message for="foo" />
</h:form>
```

As above you get your messages displayed at both levels.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! But I really forgot to add some information. I would like to use the @violating in the showMessageFor, but with that the problems still happens, any other suggestion?

Comment: globalOnly does not display any messages in the p:messages, since the @violating displays messages for each field. Thanks for the idea though. The problem is that I'm required to show both the p:messages and p:message, so I can't use your solution, but it may work for someone, so I'll mark it as solved, just my use case that doesn't. I'll stick with my groups solution.

Comment: Should that be so then I will suggest you use `o:messages`. I updated the answer to include you use case.